# Jpos printer not working after exporting .jar file from netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, javapos

I am working with EPSON pos printer , while testing from netbeans printer works fine but after exporting .jar file and try to print it does not work .
 thanks

Comment: I have done it my self . Now it works perfectly .thanks to all to tried to help me.

Comment: so what was your problem and what did you do to solve it? Would appreciate if you would share with us your invaluable experience!

Comment: I just put jpos.xml , lib files and application file altogether in same folder. If Anyone need help i am ready to help. @Chiggiddi

Comment: Hi there, really appreciate your findings. Could you specify or make a screenshot of your folder hierarchy. The problem I have is that I can print with he EPSON with its java-based Testapp but I am unable to do so in Netbeans.

Comment: did you put lib from java-pos site [link] http://www.javapos.com/ ?

Comment: give me your email and detail of your printer @Chiggiddi

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for your kindness. Since stackoverflow doesn't support private messages; just send me a message c.fei@gmx.com

Comment: ok @Chiggiddi i will email you.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue and solved by my self and now working fine. You just have to put all the .jar files required for your Printer model and JavaPOS version. My printer is EPSON TM-T82II and JavaPOS ADK_1.14.1.0.

My .jar files are as follows: `epsonupos.admin.jar`, `epsonupos.core.v1.14.0001.jar`, `epsonupos.T82II.jar`, `jpos1141.jar`, `pos.v4.0001.jar`, `uposcommon.core.v1.14.0001.jar`, `uposcommon.jar`, 
`xercesImpl.jar`.

You can find those .jar files in your JavaPOS service files path which you selected while installing JavaPOS.

Comment: And you also have put  jpos.xml file  and your application file together ,

Comment: EPSON is such a hopeless company! Yesterday I called the German representative office and I was get rid off by the words: "EPSON does not provide any support for Linux, but we provide drivers for Linux!". They even told me to go to the Internet to look around Linux forums to get some help. This is what I don't understand: Even Bixolon, Star, Citizen offer Linux support while Epson (biggest company for POS printers) offers none!